# How do I import individual components using dynamic imports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

Right now, I have a react app which imports individual items or components like this

```
import { Component1, Component2, Component3 } from "some-react-library";
import Component4 from "another-react-library";
```

Let's suppose I want to lazy-load these components instead. I know how to import `Component4` like this

```
const Component4 = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("another-react-library");
})
```

Similarly, I'd like to import `Component1`, `Component2` and `Component3` as well. What's the syntax for using dynamic `import()` method for individual components/objects?

Wouldn't something like ..

```
const Component2 = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("some-react-library").Component2
})
```

.. needlessly load the whole `some-react-library` first, and then pick `Component2` from it?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the approach you mentioned. It loads the whole library, then you can take whatever you want out of it.

What you want depends on how library is built and published. For example, it's possible to import just a module of `lodash`. You can look at this [npm search](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:lodash-modularized) and see how they are published independently. But for some, it is not possible since they aren't going in such a way.